# Batch action edits all users instead of selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So I have batch actions which should ban/unban admin users. They do it well, but infact they ban/unban all users, not just selected. I took form of batch action from example in documentation.https://activeadmin.info/9-batch-actions.html

```
batch_action :ban do |ids|
batch_action_collection.find(ids).each do |ids|
AdminUser.update  ban: false
end
redirect_to collection_path, alert: "The user has been blocked" 
end
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Actually it wasn't hard. Maybe someone will have the same problem so I post my way to resolve this problem

```
batch_action :unban do |ids|
AdminUser.find(ids).each do |v|
  v.update ban:true
end
redirect_to collection_path, alert: "The user has been unblocked"
end
```

v is just a letter, so you can choose anyone you want.